# What sefer is יפ"ל - referred to in the כף החיים

Tags: jewish-books

What sefer is this? - many references in the Kaf haChayim to a יפ"ל

In searches I've only found it in the Kaf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ספר יפה ללב on Shulchan Aruch. His name is רבי רחמים נסים יצחק פלאג'י. He was the son of Rav Chaim Palgai.

Sample page of the Sefer:

[image]

Comment: OIC, I had thought the Kaf was by the Chida, now I see it's by Chaim Palagi.

Comment: There's two Kaf hachaims. The other is by Rav Chaim Sofer